# How to direct open Internal Storage (Root explorer)?

Tags: android, explorer

I want to click the button,and then turn to `Internal Storage` directly.
My code:

```
private void openSystemFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It shows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then finally, I want to click the button, it turns to the third image directly, not the second and then third, how can I do what?

Comment: Yes, I have same problem, because I have any type of file, it may be image or text file or etc. then how to detect action to open that file directly.